# Android Studio, не добавляет запись в БД Sqlite

Tags: java, android-studio, sqlite, insert

Подскажите пожалуйста, почему может не добавляться запись в БД? Никакой ошибки не возникает, всё работает, но запись просто не добавляет.

Код добавления записи:

```
public static void insertRowAchievements(Context context) {
    databaseHelper = new DatabaseHelper(context);

    // создаем базу данных
    databaseHelper.create_db();

    // открываем подключение
    db = databaseHelper.open();

    // Создаем объект ContentValues, где имена столбцов ключи,
    // а информация о пользователе является значениями ключей
    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();

    contentValues.put(COLUMN_TITTLE, "Новичёк"); // 1
    contentValues.put(COLUMN_DESCRIPTION, "Пройдите 5 уровней подряд");
    contentValues.put(COLUMN_REWARD, 5);
    contentValues.put(COLUMN_STATUS, false);
    contentValues.put(COLUMN_ID_USER, id);
    db.insert(TABLE_ACHIEVEMENTS, null, contentValues);
    contentValues.clear();
    db.close();
}
```

Код таблицы БД, куда пытаюсь добавить запись:

```
CREATE TABLE `achievements` (
    `_id`   INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT UNIQUE,
    `tittle`    TEXT NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    `description`   TEXT NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    `reward`    INTEGER NOT NULL,
    `status`    BOOLEAN NOT NULL DEFAULT 'false',
    `count_levels`  INTEGER DEFAULT NULL,
    `count_money`   INTEGER DEFAULT NULL,
    `count_eating`  INTEGER DEFAULT NULL,
    `count_wins`    INTEGER DEFAULT NULL,
    `id_user`   INTEGER NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY(`id_user`) REFERENCES `users`(`_id`) ON DELETE SET NULL
);
```

Comment: Покажите ваш метод db.insert(TABLE_ACHIEVEMENTS, null, contentValues);
И еще рекомендую перенести инициализацию бд так чтоб она открывалась один раз. Один из вариантов это перенести её в Application

Comment: Это встроенный метод в классе SQLiteDatabase (SQLiteDatabase db).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте заменить ваш метод `insert()` на этот

```
   public long insert(String table, String nullColumnHack, ContentValues values) {
        return myDataBase.insert(table, nullColumnHack, values);
    }
```

где `myDataBase` экземпляр `SQLiteDatabase`.

Если вам нужно я могу скинуть свой класс `DataBaseHelper`, который использую у себя. Я уверен что вы можете его у себя использовать

Comment: И в чём смысл этой обёртки?